# PyGLM install fails in MSYS2

Tags: msys2

I recently installed an MSYS2 environment on my machine. I am now trying to install PyGLM. This is the error I get:

```
$ pip install pyglm
Collecting pyglm
  Using cached PyGLM-2.7.0.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:/msys64/tmp/pip-install-88wotzzc/pyglm_854e29f0eabd4c5197232054307aae92/setup.py", line 33, in <module>
          shutil.copy2("pyglm-typing/src/glm_typing/__init__.py", "glm-stubs/glm_typing.py")
        File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
          copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
        File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
          with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pyglm-typing/src/glm_typing/__init__.py'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried downloading wheels from https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/#files
but I always end up with

```
ERROR: PyGLM-2.7.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PyGLM-2.7 is just broken (or for some reason just does not work on my machine for whatever reason). When I try to install from source I get exactly the same error. This here, though:

```
pip install pyglm==2.5.0
```

works like a charm.